# Add Days to Wordpress get_the_date function

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I need to add an expiry date to an xml feed for a jobs website in YYYYMMDD format.

The position needs to expire 60 days after the initial posting date, i've used the code below to return the date each job was posted.

```
// Job date
$date = $xml_document->createElement("date");
$date->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( get_the_date('Ymd') ));
$job_element->appendChild($date);
```

How do I simply grab this date and add 60 days to it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date = $xml_document->createElement("date");
$wpDate = get_the_date('Y-m-d');
$wpDate = new DateTime($wpDate);
$wpDate->add(new DateInterval('P60D')); // P60D means a period of 60 days
$wpDate = $wpDate->format('Ymd');
$date->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( $wpDate ));
$job_element->appendChild($date);
```

Comment: sorry to be a noob, but how do i integrate this in to the code above? thanks again for the response